# Check condition and send out parameter value from procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a procedure where it needs to check the value of a column IsLoggedIn and send the outparameter with -1 if "IsLoggedIn" is 1 else it needs to send the user information.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_bh_loginverify1`(IN `user_email` VARCHAR(100), OUT `p_islogged` INT)
    NO SQL
BEGIN

IF (EXISTS(select * FROM user_details WHERE user_email = user_email)) 
    THEN
        SET p_islogged = 1; SELECT 0;
END IF;

(select UD.user_id, UD.user_name, UD.password, UD.password_salt, UD.user_email, R.role_id as role, R.role_name as role_name from user_details UD 
 JOIN roles R on R.role_id = UD.role 
 where (UD.user_email = user_email OR UD.user_name = user_email));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Pardon me for asking, but what is your question? Does the above work? If not, does it return an error, or the wrong result? What do you need help with?

Comment: I notice you say in your description above that you want some kind of if/else logic, but then you don't use `ELSE` in your procedure.

Comment: Yes, I needs to add else with out parameter as 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, always name your procedure input parameters something different from the columns of your table. For example you do this:

```
IF (EXISTS(select * FROM user_details WHERE user_email = user_email))
```

How is MySQL supposed to know that `user_email` is the column in the table, but `user_email` is the procedure parameter of that name? It doesn't -- it assumes both are references to the column. It compares the column `user_email` to itself, which will return *every* row where the column is not NULL, because it's always true that `user_email = user_email`. In other words, that the column is equal to itself (unless it's NULL).

You shoudl name the procedure parameter something distinct from the column name:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_bh_loginverify1`(IN `p_user_email` VARCHAR(100), OUT `p_islogged` INT)
```

You used `NO SQL` which [means](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html): "indicates that the routine contains no SQL statements." But that's not true, because you do have SQL statement in this procedure.

You should use:

```
READS SQL DATA
```

You said you want to return -1 in the OUT parameter, but you set 1. So you should set -1.

Next you mentioned "else it sends user information" which suggests you want that result set to be returned only conditionally. But your code returns that user information outside the `IF/END IF` block, so it happens regardless of the condition. You should use an `ELSE` block to do this.

Notice the use of `p_user_email` in the queries below, to make it distinct from `user_email`.

```
BEGIN

    IF (EXISTS(select * FROM user_details WHERE user_email = p_user_email)) 
        THEN
            SET p_islogged = -1; 
    ELSE
        SELECT UD.user_id, UD.user_name, UD.password, UD.password_salt, UD.user_email, 
            R.role_id as role, R.role_name as role_name 
        FROM user_details UD 
        JOIN roles R ON R.role_id = UD.role 
        WHERE UD.user_email = p_user_email OR UD.user_name = p_user_email;
    END IF;

END
```

I don't think you need `SELECT 0;` at all. MySQL stored procedures can return no result set, or one result set, or multiple result sets.